# Using conversion-functions in XACML

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, alfa, authzforce

Could you explain me please how I can use the conversion-functions from provided list of XACML for creating the Condition in Rule of Policy. For example that function.

```
urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:integer-from-string
```

I'm using AuthzForce, and my `Apply` contains `AttributeValue` and `AttributeDesignator`. My PDP Request contains only string types and I would like to do a conversion in needed types in the policy.

I tried to do so, but I got `error-message - policyset is invalid`.

```xml
<Condition>
    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:and">
        <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:all-of">
            <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-greater-than-or-equal"/>
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">100</AttributeValue>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:integer-from-string">         
                <AttributeDesignator
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:testvalue"
                        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:testvalue-category:strvalue"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
        </Apply>
    </Apply>
</Condition>
```

Comment: Could you give the full error message? There should be more information about which part of the policy is invalid. Anyway, I see at list one mistake, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AuthzForce (esp. authzforce core), the full error message should give more info about which part of the policy is invalid.
Anyway, I see at least one issue (which is a very common mistake when starting with XACML): an `AttributeDesignator` is considered as Bag of values (i.e. possibly multivalued). Therefore, you cannot apply the `integer-from-string` function directly on it because it takes a simple string value as input, not a Bag. The fix consists to apply one of the *-`one-and-only` functions (which turns a single-valued bag into a single value) on the `AttributeDesignator` first, depending on the datatype:

```xml
...
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:function:integer-from-string">
   <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-one-and-only">         
                <AttributeDesignator
                        Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:testvalue"
                        AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:testvalue-category:strvalue"
                        DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"
                        MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
    </Apply>
...
```

### More info

- [XACML 3.0 standard](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-core-spec-en.html)
- [In XACML what is the StringOneAndOnly function?](https://www.axiomatics.com/in-xacml-what-is-the-stringoneandonly-function/)